# Prepending lists to lists

Tags: haskell

This is probably a very simple question.

Given two lists of strings, xs and ys, I need a list of lists where the two have been prepended.

For instance,

`body = ["1", "2"]
 suffixes = ["a", "b", "c"]`

would give the output

`[["1a", "1b", "1c"], ["2a", "2b", "2c"]]`

From what I understand, haskell uses `map` where other languages would use `for each`, so I tried mapping the append function to the list,
`map (++"1") suffixes`
but I can't figure out how to apply this dynamically to `["1", "2"]` instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: Maybe another map?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not need the list boundaries (a very common case):

```
Control.Applicative> liftA2 (++) ["1", "2"] ["a", "b", "c"]
["1a","1b","1c","2a","2b","2c"]
```

Otherwise, just nest your call to `map`:

```
> map (\prefix -> map (prefix++) ["a", "b", "c"]) ["1", "2"]
[["1a","1b","1c"],["2a","2b","2c"]]
```

Comment: Another possibility that extends more easily to working with more than two lists of choices: `concat <$> sequence [["1", "2"], ["a", "b", "c"]]`